# Get a static property from class in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, reflection, actionscript

I have this class

```
package somePackage
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static const FOO: SomeClass = new SomeClass("0");
        public static const BAR: SomeClass = new SomeClass("1");
        }
}
```

I want to be able to get those static property given it's name.

Example:

```
public static function getProperty(propertyName: String): SomeClass {
    //don't know what goes here
}

var property1:SomeClass = SomeClass.getProperty("FOO"); // property1 == SomeClass.FOO
var property2:SomeClass = SomeClass.getProperty("BAR"); // property2 == SomeClass.Bar
```

Comment: Why do you need to be able to write "FOO" but not FOO?

Comment: I'm not writing it. It comes written as a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use square brackets like this:

```
SomeClass['FOO']
```

Or if you want to put it in a method that returns a typed object:

```
public static function getProperty(propertyName: String):SomeClass {
    return SomeClass[propertyName]
}
```